# Calling an IBaction in a alertView if statement

Tags: ios, if-statement, xcode4.5, uialertview, ibaction

Me and my buddy are working on an app, we're total newbies but have come a long way with books and goggling.

We're stuck now on this thing. We have a bunch of texfields that we have clear button linked to it with this action, but then we want that action to be called if you click "Yes" on one of the alert view buttons.

```
- (IBAction)clearText:(id)sender {

Spelare1Slag1.text = @"";
Spelare1Slag2.text = @"";
```

}

We also have this alert view:

```
        alertDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle: @"Warning"
    message: @"Do you want to delete?"
    delegate: self
    cancelButtonTitle: @"No"
    otherButtonTitles: @"Yes", nil];

- (void)alertView: (UIAlertView *)alertView
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSString *buttonTitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"No"]) {
    }

    else if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Yes"]){
        Spelare1Slag1.text = @"";
    }
```

}

So this is how we think we should do it, but we don't know what to put in the else if statement. We want the textfields to clear when you press the "yes" button in the alert view, and not when you press "no"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clearText method, I'm assuming, is a custom method you created to delete the text in both the fields right? So instead of it being an IBAction, it should be a void method :

```
- (void)clearText {
Spelare1Slag1.text = @"";
Spelare1Slag2.text = @"";
}
```

Now all you need to do in your UIAlertView delegate method, is call the clearText method :

```
- (void)alertView: (UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
NSString *buttonTitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
  if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Yes"]){
      [self clearText];
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This looks promising, i will look in to it tomorrow, im not at home atm!

Answer (score 2):

You could dismiss the `AlertView` in case of  user has clicked `NO` If I understand question properly.

You could dismiss the alertview like this

```
[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

but make sure to see if `NO` has index 0 or 1, if you are not sure  then just do like this

```
[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:nil animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Methods of type `IBAction` are just like any other method, and you can call them in your code directly. In fact, `IBAction` is simply a macro evaluating to `void`. Usually, you'll pass a `nil` sender argument when it needs to be called outside of the context of a target / action event being triggered.

```
[self clearText:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to check the actual button text? Checking the button index is the most efficient way to go. If you have two fields in your alertView, just check if the index is 0 or 1 and your good to go. Your doing extra work checking the actual text.

And btw, just do a check for the index of the YES button if you don't need to do anything specific when they press no. (Don't check both indexes if you don't need to).